# Flutter Auto Translation

Tags: flutter, translation

I have a flutter app in English.
And I want to add another language to it like arabic.
But I don't want to extract all texts that needs translations manually.

for example I have texts in the Text('') widget and In other String variables that need to be translated.

I want to generate a json file with the values like this

```
{
"Text 1":"Text 1",
"Text 2":"Text 2"
}
```

after that I will use any tool to translate this json file using Google Translate.
The hard part is extracting texts from the dart code.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [Flutter Intl](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=localizely.flutter-intl) VS Code extension to extract your strings into the ARB file.

It won't be fully automatic, you'll still have to go through all your texts and extract them using [code actions](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/refactoring#_code-actions-quick-fixes-and-refactorings). The dialog will ask you to enter the string key, which will be extracted to ARB files together with the selected content.

After extracting that, you can use any localization platform to translate the extracted texts. For example, Crowdin has great [support for ARB file format](https://store.crowdin.com/arb) and also [Flutter SDK](https://github.com/crowdin/flutter-sdk) for instant translation delivery to your application.

Answer (score 0):

Consider using [GetX](https://pub.dev/packages/get) for translations in your Flutter app. It offers a user-friendly and customizable solution, with separate translation files for each language and the convenient key.tr function for accessing translations. Check out the documentation and tutorials to learn more.

https://prashantv03.medium.com/flutter-getx-state-management-f60d59b5778b

```
    import 'package:get/get.dart';

class Messages extends Translations {
  @override
  Map<String, Map<String, String>> get keys => {
        'en_US': {
          'hello': 'Hello World',
        },
        'de_DE': {
          'hello': 'Hallo Welt',
        }
      };
}
```

Manage translations for different languages at every text widget which you can show in Application like below :

```
Text('hello'.tr);
```